# How to close a tab with a directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to put a close button on a tab and then remove that tab out from the DOM...

I am probably not doing it in the correct Angular way, because when I do it the tabset dies and I cannot change tabs anymore.

I do not want to use ng-repeat but instead let the directive work when people have manually defined their tabs

I created [a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0XvU63ymOiopVJmUJRyl) showing the problem.

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').directive('tabClosable', function() {
   return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '^tab',
    link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
      console.log(element);
      var closeButton = angular.element('<button>x</button>');
      element.children().eq(0).append(closeButton);
      closeButton.bind('click', function() {
        console.log("click");
        element.remove();
      });

      scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        console.log('scope destroyed: ');
        console.log(scope.$id);
      })
    }
  };
});
```

I get multiple scope destroyed so I am guessing that I'm pulling down too many scopes by removing the element?

Comment: have you tried `window.close()` ?

Comment: Maybe I was unclear but I want to close a inpage tabset tab (see the plunker) and not a browser tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular version < 1.3 had this issue. Whenever any dom node inside transcluded directive is removed, all the scope inside it will be destroyed.

Check this for more details: http://fiddle.jshell.net/6qdhX/19/

Upgrade your angular version to 1.3

If you still want to continue with 1.2, you can try the below solution. 
1. create `appTransclude` directive.

```
directive('appTransclude', function() {
    "use strict";
    return {
        "restrict": "A",
        "link": function (scope, element, attrs, nullCtrl, transcludeFn) {
            var elScope = element.scope();

            transcludeFn(elScope, function (clone) {
                element.append(clone);
            });
        }
    };
};
```

2. Use this directive instead of `ng-transclude`.

Comment: Thanks for your update. I'm at Angular 1.2 because we need to support IE8. I do not know how much Angular 1.3 really breaks IE8 functionality but maybe I need to start investigate it... Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I will upgrade to 1.3 and see if I can reproduce the error